Can't set value from snapshot with firebase
I'm trying to set value for an object from Snapshot from firebase. Somehow it only set 1 value out of 3 of that object.
This is my object
public class StudentDataClass {

    private String Name;
    private  String MSSV;

    private String dataImage;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getMSSV() {
        return MSSV;
    }

    public String getDataImage() {
        return dataImage;
    }

    public StudentDataClass(String name,String mssv, String dataImage) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.MSSV = mssv;
        this.dataImage = dataImage;
        //this.dataImage = (dataImage == null || dataImage.isEmpty()) ? "default_url_or_empty" : dataImage;
    }

    public StudentDataClass(){

    }
}

List<StudentDataClass> studentList;

studentList = new ArrayList<>();

this is database snapshot codes.
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://android-app-eae36-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app").getReference("Students");

dialog.show();

eventListener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        studentList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot itemShapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
            StudentDataClass student = itemShapshot.getValue(StudentDataClass.class);
            studentList.add(student);
        }
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

the Object got dataImage but not Name or MSSV

And this is my Database


In order to be able to set the value of a property from the database to a field/property in your Java class, the Firebase SDK looks for a field or setter method that matches its name and type.
Since you have no setter methods in StudentDataClass, the SDK looks at the fields: Name, MSSV, and dataImage. And of those, only dataImage has a name that exactly matches a property in the database - the other two have different casing between DB and code.
You have a few options:

Rename the properties in the database to match the exact names in the code.
Rename the fields in your Java class to match the exact property names in the database.
Add setter methods to the Java code, as setName actually matches a database property name, and setMssv matches a property named mssv.
Use a PropertyName annotation in the code to specify the property name it maps to.

